# multiple group matches after specific word match

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a string like this:

```
title1:
{key1=val1,
key2=val2,},
{key1=val1,
key2=val2,},
title2:
{key1=val1,
key2=val2,},
```

and i would like to have the block after "title1" starting at the first "{" and ending at the second "}," right before "title2". What would be the regex for that one?
I tried doing something like:

```
^title1:\s*(?:{[^}\s\S]*},)*
```

As I understood, this should match if

- the first characters in line are "title1:"
- optionally followed by a white space(the line break)
- followed by a repeating group
- which starts with a "{", is followed by any amount of characters(whitespaces or not) but the closing "}" and ends with the "},"

But unfortunately regex is thinking different :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^}\s\S]` - this pattern would never match regardless of input:

```
!(<curve brace> | <spaces> | <not-spaces>) = 
!<curve brace>  & !<space> & !<not-space>  = false
```

`},)` - here you've missed optional spaces `},\s*)`

Working pattern:

```
String str = "title1:\n" +
    "{key1=val1,\n" +
    "key2=val2,},\n" +
    "{key1=val1,\n" +
    "key2=val2,},\n" +
    "title2:\n" +
    "{key1=val1,\n" +
    "key2=val2,},";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^title1:\\s*(?:\\{[^}]*},\\s*)*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println("> " + matcher.find());
System.out.println("> " + matcher.group());
```

Output:

```
> true
> title1:
{key1=val1,
key2=val2,},
{key1=val1,
key2=val2,},
```

Comment: I thought the [] brackets mean one of the set? So I read that as either not the curly brace or the whitespace or the non whitespace... Now that I write it, I guess it does not really make sense. So what I wanted was just the not curly brace. Thanks for the hint with the missed line break as well.